# LUIS Usage Status

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

In Azure Portal, I have created **Web App Bot** using **Basic Bot template** which includes LUIS creation automatically.

LUIS has **Free2 - Web/Container** comes with 10,000 transactions* free per month (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-services/).

a. How to I see my usage of the 10,000 transactions?
b. In my Azure Cost & Billing, I do not see the LUIS except the Bot Service, App Service and App Service Plan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In the Azure Portal, under the list of resources there should be a Cognitive Services resource for luis, usually it will have the `-luis` suffix. Under the overview tab of this resource you will be able see your current usage:

[image]

In terms of viewing your LUIS costs, these can be accessed from under the Cost & Billing > Cost anaylsis section:

[image]

Comment: All - Resource Group: [link](https://ibb.co/rFYF8y2)
LUIS Portal: [link](https://ibb.co/Jm7wzFH)

Referring to my screencaps, I cannot find the service in my Azure Portal, and in my LUIS there are a few apps.

Comment: Interesting - Have you checked out the link on the [official GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot#deploy-the-bot-to-azure) for the Core Bot sample which links to the [deployment instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=newrg)? The `template-xxx.json` files mentioned in the instructions will be inside the `DeploymentTemplates` folder in your project.

Comment: Yup. I'm wondering why the LUIS is not in my Azure Portal if I created the Web App Bot via Azure Portal's Add Resources function.

Comment: I have just created a Basic Bot through the Azure portal and cam confirm that no cognitive resources are created along with it. What I suspect is that the bot code itself has handling for LUIS but you need to manually create then assign a Cognitive Services resource to your LUIS apps as per the create and assign steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/get-started-portal-deploy-app). However, what I would suggest instead is downloading and installing [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4).

Comment: Actually it looks like only the Virtual Assistant template will automatically deploy cognitive services as part of the deployment script. So you will have to manually create and assign a cognitive resource for your LUIS app as per my link above. There is a sample bot that you can download [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) which just needs your QnA Maker and LUIS details added to the appsettings.json file to work.

Comment: Once you’ve got it working locally follow the deployment instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: Will give it a try. I guess I can create a new Cognitive Services via Azure Portal, export and import the app, then update my bot to talk to the new Cognitive service.

Comment: Yes you will be able to do that by following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/get-started-portal-deploy-app) to associate your cognitive service resource with your LUIS app. Then you will just need to update you appsettings.json file to ensure that you have the keys and ids for your LUIS app setup.

Comment: Now I use back the same luis app, but assign resource (Under Key and Endpoints) to the new azure resource I have created, and update the key in the appsetting.json file. Let's see if the usage is reflected in the azure portal later on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem @LawHuiSheng when you check back later on and see the changes reflected please upvote and mark this answer as accepted if it solved your question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to see LUIS' usage, we need to create another LUIS resource in Azure and link the Azure resource via LUIS's portal.